# Launch iPhone camera app with tool bar

Tags: ios, swift, camera

Is it possible to launch default camera app with tool bar (filters, timer option, etc. - marked with orange frame)?

[image]

The following code gives me only flash icon:

```
var imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
present(imagePickerController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIImagePickerController` is a slimmed down version of the camera widget, as opposed to the native camera app 'embedded' in your app. The extended functionality of the native camera app is not available in the widget, but you can mimic most of it yourself.

By adding custom buttons to the view controller before it appears, you can give the impression that the extra buttons are in the toolbar; however, you will have to code the functionality of such buttons yourself.

It's a shame, but it's unfortunately the way it goes.